# Can this Redshift Postgresql query be optimized using an UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am creating a session id for clickstream data. If a user is inactive for over 30 minutes between his activity (i.e., time difference between records that have the link-chain), then a new session id is created and assigned.

As of now, I am able to create a whole new table with this new session id being assigned as a seperate column from the data available in the main table.

This is computationally expensive query and occupies more storage space as it is creating a whole new table (when main table still exists at the same time). I had to delete the main table once this new table was created.

Can session id be assigned and entire process be done without creating a new table?
The optimized query needs to work in Redshift Postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE <new_table_name> AS
SELECT * , userid || '_' || SUM(session) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date rows unbounded preceding) AS session_id
FROM (
  SELECT *
    , CASE 
              WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date) - LAG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date)) OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date) >= 30 * 60 
              THEN 1
              WHEN row_number() over (partition by userid order by date) = 1
              THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END as session
    FROM
      <table_name>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This (after adding a session column)?

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET session=s.session
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, date,
        CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date) - LAG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date))
            OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY date) >= 30 * 60 THEN 1
        WHEN row_number() over (partition by userid order by date) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END as session
    FROM <table_name>
) s where <table_name>.user_id = s.user_id and <table_name>.date = s.date
```